# Movie identification: man bending a spoon with mind power

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching an old movie (or TV series) with a scene which a man held a spoon with one hand and bent it with his mind. A few other points I am not sure if I remember correctly:

1. the man was after some police training?
2. the man had the power due to nuclear radiation?

It's definitely not *The Matrix*. It might be shot in 1980s, coloured. The characters were very likely to be speaking English.

EDIT: I remember the man was sitting beside a table.

Comment: It definitely wasn't real life and you were watching Uri Geller? :D Have a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if it jogs your memory for any more details (year, black and white or colour etc)

Comment: Emm Uri Geller wasn't involved in nuclear radiation was he? ;-)

Comment: @user122973 - I expect if you ask him, he'll claim to have been involved in *anything* that gets him one nanosecond of additional publicity

Comment: Super Fuzz? I don't remember spoon bending per se, but it has accidental nuclear exposure, telekinesis, and it is so eighties, it hurts.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess,you might try [Mindbender](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113826/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

It's a biopic of [Uri Geller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uri_Geller), and spoon bending is  Uri's signature trick.

I haven't seen it, but it must contain at least one spoon bending scene.

Comment: If this is the answer, the question is off topic.

Comment: @James McLeod, why is it off topic? Uri Geller  claims to have paranormal powers. If it is even slightly hinted as such in the movie, it counts as SF.

Comment: Uri Geller is a real person. If we accept his powers as genuine, the movie shows reality and is off topic. If he has no paranormal powers, then the movie shows a charlatan's con game, and is off topic. Either way, it cannot be science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: You could say the same about Baron Munchhausen. If his stories were true, they are real and not SF. If they are false, then he's just a liar. ( I will say about Geller that he's an entertainer, not a charlatan. The stories he tells are all part of his act.  He is no more a charlatan than David Copperfield or Doug Henning, who also lie as part of their act)

Comment: Baron Munchausen is a fictional character, Uri Geller less so. I don’t think Uri Geller is quite the same as Copperfield or Henning as he actually claimed originally to have psychic powers, whereas the other two never claimed to do anything other than tricks, I mean *illusions*.

Comment: There actually was a real Baron, famed for his tall tales. Rudolf Erich Raspe  wrote an unauthorized book, which upset the real Baron. It's a fictionalized version of a real person. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_Munchausen   As for Uri Geller, most conjurers consider him to be a performer, not a charlatan, and one of the greats. http://magicians.co.uk/news/international-magic-award/#more-235  I could go into detail on this, but it's the wrong forum.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't think this is the one I watched.